# Active Directory cn=IP Security read data

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019

I am trying to read cn=IP Security,cn=System,dc= from the domain controller. Although, i have the highest read permissions (as a user) and can read from other containers (such as Computers, Users etc) but cannot read this specific container when i send a LDAP search query to retrieve the data. Same work for the domain admin account. There is no AV,firewall or network appliance which is blocking or filtering the information. I am trying to access from Windows 2019 Server to MS Active Directory 2016. It seems that the read permissions are not working on this specific container. I can read from the same container in another network using the same setup.

Any suggestions on what could be causing this issue? Thanks

Comment: How are you attacking the AD? PowerShell?

Comment: Yes, through PowerShell and also used a third party tool with builtin LDAP query.

Comment: Where is the object located exactly please? I want to check it on my AD

Comment: Active Directory based IPSec policies are stored in CN=IP Security, CN=System,DC=domainname,DC=topleveldomain